# Cabal cannot resolve dependencies for Idris

Tags: homebrew, ghc, cabal, idris

I'm new to the Haskell ecosystem and trying to install Idris on my MacOS Catalina.

So after

```
$ brew install ghc
$ brew install cabal-install
```

I have `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.8.2` and `cabal-install version 3.0.0.0`. Then I'm trying to install Idris but

```
$ cabal update; cabal install idris
```

from [official docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/starting.html) fails with

> Resolving dependencies... cabal: Could not resolve dependencies: [__6]
>   fail (backjumping, conflict set: template-haskell, text, time) After
>   searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
>   goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: hashable, trifecta, base,
>   idris, text, template-haskell, time, pretty, blaze-builder,
>   blaze-markup, idris:setup.Cabal, zlib, unordered-containers, ivor,
>   optparse-applicative Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to
>   improve the error message.

Running with the flag mentioned in message doesn't help too.

Should I try building from sources or is there any other good way to fix this error?

Comment: installing with `brew install idris` directly eliminated the question altogether but I will leave it in case somebody knows how to fix cabal here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PR supporting those versions was just merged in January: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/pull/4808

However, the last release on Hackage was July of last year:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/idris

So I'd assume the currently released version doesn't build on GHC 8.8.
You could build current master from the git repo.
Or you could install the idris-current.pkg binary from https://www.idris-lang.org/download/ instead of building it yourself from source.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux I needed to install zlib outside of cabal, you might need to do that. I see that in your list of failed packages.